# If I'm building my app that runs on minimum Android 5.0 lollipop, what does it mean for phones with lower versions?

Tags: android, google-play

What if a phone has Android version under 5.0, does it mean my app won't run on their android devices?

Will my app not be even be downloadable on their devices like with Apple devices or with Android it's different and it will be able to download but the app will become glitchy and break down and lead to poor google play store reviews full of "broken app"?

Comment: It means that you're **limiting your app** to those devices which API levels are **at least** equal to Lollipop.

Answer (score 7):

> What if a phone has Android version under 5.0, does it mean my app won't run on their android devices?

Correct

> Will my app not be even be downloadable on their devices

Correct